# setting the character encoding for a GZIPPed javascript file in JSF

Tags: jsf, character-encoding, glassfish-3

I'm facing a problem in setting the character encoding of a javascript file response for my JSF application after enabling the compression in Glassfish server.

the problem is that the javascript file contains Arabic characters and i was setting the character encoding for the response using a filter and it was working fine but after enabling the compressing option in glassfish to solve a performance issue, the javascript started to produce errors in the browser console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

and while investigating i removed the `setCharcterEncoding("UTF-8")` and the js file started to work as expected again but of course without showing the Arabic character.

how can i set the character encoding for this response.

the doFilter() function:

```
  @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest sr, ServletResponse sr1, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
    sr1.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
}
```

the web.xml filter section:

```
 <filter-name>JSEncoding Filter </filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        util.JSEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JSEncoding Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

HTTP Response Header:

```
server: Glassfish server open source edition 3.1.2.2
x-powered-by: JSF/2.0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: w/"49813-1424163932095"
Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Feb 2015 09:05:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chuncked
Content-Encoding: gzip
vary:- Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 17 Feb 2015 09:52:44 GMTa
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you finding some problems with JavaScript files with some characters in Arabic language. This problem should not be related to JSF as Facelets already defaults to `UTF-8`. The problem, if any should however, be related to some other environments like an IDE or some text editors which you are supposed to use which may not have already been set to use `UTF-8`.

Comment: actually I'm using primefaces which calls the request.getparameters() early in the life cycle that it's too late for jsf to set the character encding, so as I mentioned I used a filter to force setting the character encoding in the response. but it's not working with gzipped files.

Comment: Are you implying that the problem still manifests when you remove that `AddExpiresHeaderResponse`?

Comment: unfortunately it does, I tested it again after sawing your comment and the problem still exists.

Comment: Please eliminate this noise from the question then. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to clean the question as much as i can in the last edit. hope this will be helpful in identifying the problem.

Comment: List the response headers retrieved by the client.

Comment: Response header are included in the last edit